# Sandcastle Help File Builder: HTML not being generated from MAML

Tags: sandcastle, shfb, maml

I have added a test.aml file to my Sandcastle project with a BuildAction of None.

I've also added a Content Layout.content file and added test.aml to the layout. When I build the help (website format only) the topic is included in the TOC but the content is not there. When I click the topic nothing happens, it remains on the previous topic.

Am I missing something or is this a known problem/limitation with SHFB?

I am using v1.9.4.0 of SHFB.

Answer (score 0):

I replied here: http://shfb.codeplex.com/discussions/405627

Also, note that v1.9.5.0 is available.  You might try upgrading to the latest release to see if that changes anything after trying the suggestions in the above noted thread.  It's best to keep SHFB related posts on the CodePlex project site since I don't frequenst StackOverflow.

Eric